# eclipse plug-in development breakpoink listeners

Tags: eclipse-cdt

in eclipse plug-in development i want print something When use cdt debug the program stops at the breakpoint , Does cdt have any related listeners?

```
public class RunTimeDataView extends ThinkTechView implements IDebugContextListener, IExecutionListener{
```